# Want to search data from JSON file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

[Output like this but without Jquery uses](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)Want to search data from JSON file data using Javascript. want to search data by ID, emp_name, salary, or age.

```
  function searchTxt(search) {
          tData = [];
        if(search.length > 1) {
            tData = users.filter(function (item) {
                for (let x in tableFields) {
                    if (item[tableFields[x]].includes(search)) {

                        return true;
                    }//console.log((item));
                }
            });
        }else {
            tData = users;
        }
        showdata(tData);
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here ? Please explain your problem with more details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have to provide some sample data.

Comment: I have write a code to access JSON file data. An the know I want to search data from JSON in order. with user inputs like.. Id, emp_name, emp_salery, emp_age.

Comment: Please note that `localhost` outside of your computer does not work, so your link is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON data is an array of objects of the same type, then you could easily create a function that takes a search ID as a parameter, loops through the data, and returns you all the data that belongs to that ID

```
function searchByID(id) {
  results = [];
  jsonData.forEach((result) => { // I can’t see the structure of your JSON, so I’m assuming it’s an array of objects here
    console.log(result[id]);
    results.push(result[id]);
  });
  return results;
}

searchByID("name");
searchByID("salary");
searchByID("location");
```

Comment: Theses are the fields of my JSON file.  tableFields = ['id', 'employee_name', 'employee_salary', 'employee_age'];

Comment: What exactly is it you’re trying to do with the data? Do you just want to search by a key and return all data matching that key?

Comment: Please visit this Link. -- https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html , I want output like this but without Jquery. If u type id/name/salary/ age got the data according.